# How do we configure CID to work with a HTTPS (TLSv1.2) website?

Tags: web8.5, microservices, cil, contextual-image-delivery

We are running SDL Web 8.5 CID micro-service on a linux environment using the start.sh script.  This service reaches out to a https website to fetch the images before then modifying them for final use.  Our https site is configured to use TLSv1.2.

When the micro-service attempts to fetch an image from our https site we receive the following error:

```
2019-08-21 14:57:55,182 WARN  ContentTypeAcquirer - Warning, could not get content type from input stream for resource 'https://www.oursite.com/en/assets/ourimage.jpg'
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:24)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:13)
        at com.ibm.jsse2.at.b(at.java:527)
```

We set the javax.net debugging to "all" and found the following in the logs:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
[...]
http-nio2-8089-exec-5, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake
[...]
http-nio2-8089-exec-5, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio2-8089-exec-5, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, protocol_version
```

This seems to indicate that our CID micro-service is using TLSv1 while our site is using TLSv1.2.

We tried modifying our JVM arguments but it does not seem to have any impact:

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

We also tried the following (to be thorough), but again, it has no impact:

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Is there any way that we can configure the CID to use TLSv1.2 for these requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using an IBM JVM (`at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:24)`).
This JVM has some specific setting that allows you to enable or disable use of TLS V1.2.

This is explained here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/matchsslcontext_tls.html#matchsslcontext_tls

Basically, you need to add this to the java options `-Dcom.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true` in the start.sh script.

Comment: That indeed fixed the issue, thanks a bunch